# How do I get selected date set by jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datapicker

I'm setting the start date of an event using jQuery UI Datepicker. Now I need to retrieve the selected date. I'm trying to use `$('#startDate').datepicker('getDate')`, but this returns **NULL**.

Using FirBug, I see that the input value is nothing :-
`<input type="text" name="startDate" value="" id="startDate" class="hasDatepicker">`

So how can I retrieve the selected date?

**PS. :** 
I found an old thread regarding he exact same issue.
http://old.nabble.com/ui.datepicker-trouble-td17846951s27240.html

But the solution here does not work for me. I just get an error message :-

> uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker

**UPDATE :**

I'm able to retrieve the selected date by using this code:

```
  var arr = $('#newEvent').serializeArray();
  alert(arr[2].value);
```

But this is by far the best way....b/w any other suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: What version of jQuery / jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback to let it push it to your data :)

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve, change your code to:

```
$('.date').live('focus', function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1930:'+(new Date).getFullYear()
    });
});
```